# map is not a function react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, product, array.prototype.map

I am rendering a product list from dummyjson
getting response from api

but showing products.map() is not a function

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
    const data = await response.json();
    return setProducts(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  },[])

  console.log(products)

  return (
    <div>
    <ul>
    {products.map((product, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <h2>{product.title}</h2>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api returns an object with a property `products` which contains the products array, so you need to do

```
{products.products.map((product, index) => {
```

Alternatively, you could store just the products array in state like so, and you can keep your existing map code.

```
return setProducts(data.products);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is an object. What you want to do is extract products from the JSON response, so in `fetchData` method you should call: `setProducts(data.products)`.